# How to exclude results in query LDAP

Tags: filter, ldap, symfony4

I need to make a web directory from an AD. However, I must exclude a portion of the tree in my results.

To schematize the structure:

```
-Telephony
----Special
----Users
----Other
```

I would like to exclude OU=Special. Or target OU=Users and OU=Other, but without having to write a line by "OU".

I went round and round about the query options, I'm here but that does not exclude the group.

```
        $ldap = Ldap::create('ext_ldap', array(
            'host' => 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
        ));
        $ldap->bind('dn', 'password');

        $query = $ldap->query('ou=Telephony,ou=XXXX,dc=XXXX,dc=XXXX,dc=XXXX,dc=XXXX', '(cn=*)', ['filter' => '|(ou=Users*)(ou=Other*)']);
```

But I still get the data from Special.

How can I make this filter?

Thank's for help

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

Defined in LDAPv3 [RFC 2254](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2251) an [ExtensibleMatch search filter](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch) requires LDAP servers to recognize a search element called an extensible match filter.

A ExtensibleMatch search filter would allow this however, ExtensibleMatch search filter is NOT supported by all LDAP Vendors. (Microsoft Active Directory as one example).

For your example, a filter similar to:
(&(|(ou:dn:=Users)(ou:dn:=Others))(objectclass=inetorgperson)(sn=willeke))
May work.